# Find all bonds associated with an equity

Tags: equities, programming, bond, python, capital-structure

I would like to use Python to programmatically find the cusips of all bonds that are currently issued by a given equity. Assume I can use any free api and bloomberg. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Bloomberg has a Python interface, so this sort of thing is much easier than it used to be when you had to encapsulate the COM or C++ interface.  First, set up a `session` as in the [Bloomberg documentation](https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/), then form a `request`

```
refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
```

Now set up your data request

```
request.append("securities", "IBM US Equity")
request.append("fields", "BOND_CHAIN")
```

send the request and wait for the response event.  Iterate over the (single security) and (single) field and you will have an iterable of Bloomberg identifiers for the bonds

Answer (score 1):

Probably a lot easier to use the Bloomberg add-ins in excel, write a macro to cycle the equities your looking for and retrieve the associated CUSIPs.

Comment: Given that there's a python bbg api, and they want to use python, why on earth would you say "probably a lot easier to use excel"?